# Start reading from a specific byte

Tags: java, android

How I can start reading from a specific byte? I have following code:

```
        try {
            while ( (len = f.read(buffer)) > 0 ) {}         
        }
```

For example, I want to start to read at byte 50.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should use the skip method.
http://developer.android.com/reference/java/io/InputStream.html#skip(long)

You can skip the number of bytes you want.

```
int nbToSkip = 50
while (nbToSkip > 0) {
   int nbSkipped = f.skip( nbToSkip );
   nbToSkip -= nbSkipped ; 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what the type of 'f' is, however I will assume it's some kind of stream.

Also, do you mean you want to read in blocks of 50 bytes, or start from the 50th byte in the stream? I'll assume the latter.

Not sure what language you are using, but here goes anyway:

Maybe there's a seek kind of function with which you can seek to a specific position in the stream, like so:

```
f.seek(50, SEEK_START);
```

otherwise you can do it the poor man's way by just reading 50 bytes, or 50 times 1 byte from the stream.

Hard to give you a good answer without any more reference.

Comment: I use java. f is class File. I want start from the 50th byte

Comment: Check devMatt's answer I think that's the one you want to go for as well